# Составить документ mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Не могу понять как составить документ, и как с ним потом работать.
Допустим БД хранит проекты которые пользователи создают. Каждый проект имеет пользователя, название, описание, также каждый проект(по идее сайт) состоит из секций, которые имеют своё название, html-код, сови стили css и содержат блоки, которые имеют своё название, html and css, и эти блоки содержат в себе элементы, имеющие своё название, html , css.

По идее у меня есть некий набор уже готовых таких наборов секций, состоящих из блоков и елиментов.

Пользователь для составления своего проекта использует готовые мои решения и изменяет их, именяет html, css... но данные изменения храняться только у пользовательского экземпляра секций,блоков,элиментов.

Я сам попробовал составить документы,но очень сильно сомневаюсь что так правильно(

```
{
  project:{
   name:'LandingPageStudio',
   description:'Some text',
   _id:'57839032',
   author:{
     name:'WebWorkDeveloper',
     id:'564359054',
     email:'webworkdeveloper@gmail.com',
     password:'seventin7'
   },
  section:[{
   _id:'1231543',
   name:'Main section',
   html_content:'<section class="main"><div class="container"></div></section>',
   css_content:'section.main{width:300px;height:100%;background:yellow}',
   blocks:[{
     _id:'5654365',
     name:'row',
     html_conetent:'<div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"></div></div>',
     css_content:'....',
     elements:[{
       _id:'3243125432',
       name:'image',
       html_content:'<image src="" alt="image">',
       css_content:'image{margin:auto;}'
     }]
   }]
  }]
  }
}
```

Проблема с пользователями, в реляционной БД я просто добавлял пользователя в нужную таблицу, а что делать тут... как будет правильно?